# how to set create regex for this string

Tags: php, regex

```
<div id="plugin-description">
    <p itemprop="description" class="shortdesc">
        BuddyPress helps you build any type of community website using WordPress, with member profiles, activity streams, user groups, messaging, and more. </p>
    <div class="description-right">
                <p class="button">
            <a itemprop="downloadUrl" href="https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/buddypress.2.6.1.1.zip">Download Version 2.6.1.1</a>
```

i need  description just with this code

```
<p itemprop="description" class="shortdesc">[a-z]</p>
```

i need download link

```
<a itemprop="downloadUrl" href="[A-Z]"></a>
```

Comment: Don't parse html with a regular expression. Use a parser.

Answer (score 0):

And [**once again**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags):

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div id="plugin-description">
    <p itemprop="description" class="shortdesc">
        BuddyPress helps you build any type of community website using WordPress.
    </p>
    <div class="description-right">
        <p class="button">
            <a itemprop="downloadUrl" href=".zip">Download Version 2.6.1.1</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$containers = $xpath->query("//div[@id='plugin-description']");

foreach ($containers as $container) {
    $description = trim($xpath->query(".//p[@itemprop='description']", $container)->item(0)->nodeValue);
    $link = $xpath->query(".//a[@itemprop='downloadUrl']/@href", $container)->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $description . $link;
}

?>
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/GtGkUn).

Comment: @Oms: See updated answer and demo link.

Answer (score 0):

There are better tools for parsing HTML than regular expressions. That said, there are times when parsing HTML with regular expressions works safely and consistently, so don't be bullied out of trying it. These cases are usually for small, known sets of HTML markup.

For this particular case, it seems that using an HTML parser would be effective leave you with more legible code. To illustrate this, I'll use a command line tool like [pup](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup), which will help you retrieve your content pretty simply. Let's pretend that the markup is stored at `/tmp/input` on your computer.

To grab the `downloadUrl`...

```
pup < /tmp/input 'a[itemprop="downloadUrl"] attr{href}'
```

To grab the `description`...

```
pup < /tmp/input 'p[itemprop="description"] text{}'
```

This I think illustrates the simplicity and benefits of using an HTML parser to grab what you're after.